# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'ux_source_2850.txt

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a file into another format with this python code which requires three arguments input file, output file and a percentage value. I call the python function in shell script and it works fine for the first time, but doesn't work the second time. The error is "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ux_source_2850.txt". But i am pretty sure this file is in this directory. Can someone please help me out.
Also, i am wondering if there is another way to call python function, like a compiled c function, so i can execute the function together with several arguments.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def convertfile(file1,file2,percentage): 
  with open(file1, "r+") as infile, open(file2, "w+") as outfile:
    outfile.write('lon lat Ve Vn Se Sn Cen Site Ref\n')
    for line in infile.readlines():
      line = line.strip()
      new_line=line + " "+percentage+" "+percentage+" "+'0.05 stat(0,0) test1'+'\n'
      outfile.write(new_line)
file1=raw_input()                                                              
file2=raw_input()                                                              
percentage=raw_input()                                                         
convertfile(file1,file2,percentage)

#!/bin/bash
infile1=ux_source_$j.txt                                                       
outfile1=ux_$j.txt                                                             
percentage1=`sort biggest_z_amp  | tail -1 | awk '{print $1*2e4}'`             
../convertfile.py<<!                                                           
$infile1                                                                       
$outfile1                                                                      
$percentage1                                                                   
!                                                                              
infile2=uy_source_$j.txt                                                       
outfile2=uy_$j.txt                                                             
../convertfile.py<<!                                                           
$infile2                                                                       
$outfile2                                                                      
$percentage1                                                                   
!
```

Comment: "But i am pretty sure this file is in this directory" Are you really sure? I think the only reason this might fail is if the file really isn't there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that your problem is in the shell script, not the Python script.  Make sure you have no trailing spaces in the lines that you give as input to the Python script.

Better still, use:

```
file1 = raw_input().strip()
file2 = raw_input().strip()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. May I ask what does "strip" do here? And i can't find anything wrong in my shell script which might cause this.

Comment: In your shell script, the lines starting with `$infile` have trailing spaces.  When the Python script reads the line, it thinks that the name of the input file is `"ux_source_2850.txt  "` (with a number of spaces at the end), and not just `"ux_source_2850.txt"`.  The `strip` method removes white characters from the beginning and the end of a string.